# what are Integer etc. in VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, oop

I have been studying a C# pdf about oop, and after reading most of it, i have decided to have a comparison between c# and vb, but i am a bit confused

in c# it is said that int is a struct. I used Visual Studio to check it. I pointed the cursor to the int of

```
int num;
```

and it says: struct System.int32 . because of this, i am sure that it is a struct which are Structure in VB

but when i have tried it in VB,

```
Dim num As Integer
```

It just says: Integer Represents a 32-bit signed integer, it doesn't say anything about being a Structure. What could this mean?

i have made a simple Structure in vb like this

```
Structure person

End Structure
```

and when i instantiate it

```
Dim jk As person
```

it says: Structure person (when i pointed the cursor in person). Isn't this mean that it will say Structure if it is a Structure, but why not on Integer?

are Integer Structure on VB? or if not, what is it?

I am just a beginner in oop and just want to study. thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb

Comment: @Claies, so it is a Structure after all? but why doesn't visual studio say it?

Comment: Design decision made by the VB team, I suppose. The fact that Integer is a struct is not particularly relevant most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the VB.NET `Integer` type is the same as the C# `int` type, and both are aliases for the .NET `System.Int32` type, which is a value type (i.e. `struct`). You can see this in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) (sort of, in that the type refers to itself as `Integer` even as it's documented as being named `Int32`), and as well you could see this in a test program, if you simply did something like e.g. declaring a variable `num` as you have above and then evaluated `num.GetType().Name`.

The tooltip that is displayed when you hover the mouse over a type is determined not by the underlying type per se or even the language itself, but rather by the editor. That you see two different things depending which language you're using means only that the people who wrote each editor made different decisions with respect to how the editor should display the type in those cases.

Why did they decide that? We can only speculate. You would have to ask the person or people who designed the editor. I would *guess* that it's because VB.NET was (is) intended to be familiar to those who used to write non-.NET Visual Basic code, and so for built-in types like `System.Int32`, they special-cased the tooltip so that it would display the type name those developers were already familiar with.